# React Native- Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Tags: react-native, expo

I created project `npx react-native init` after creating some UI screens I need to migrate to the expo, I created a new project using `expo init` I copy all files from old project to the new one but I got this error.

any hint where to start from

```
 ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Performance/Systrace.js:216:3
    Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
      214 |   // with numeric IDs
      215 |   // TODO(davidaurelio) Scan polyfills for dependencies, too (t9759686)
    > 216 |   (require: $FlowFixMe).Systrace = Systrace;
          |   ^
      217 | }
      218 | 
      219 | module.exports = Systrace;
```

**packages.json**

```
{
  "name": "shiftmanagement",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~10.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^3.3.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it was not easy to get what cause this issue so I upload my code to https://snack.expo.dev/ which gives me better insight into what was happing

the error come from this import

```
import { Colors } from "react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen";
```

remove it fixed the issue

Comment: Just so you know, you just saved a life.